# stop current event jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have registered event to do ajax call on an anchor tag in jquery.

However, when I click on the anchor, I check some conditions, it the conditions are not met I have to stop the event to be executing further. I dont want to do ajax call when some conditions are failed.

But I am unable to achieve that it is still doing ajax call.

registering event on load of page:

```
 new d2.EventHandler({
                name: "create folder click handler",
                selector: "a.d2-createfldr",
                isAjax: true,
                requestData: $.proxy(self._eventHndlr_requestData, self),  //creates req. data json
                url: url,
                success: $.proxy(self._onAjaxSuccess_htmlSwap, self)
            }),
```

In the method _eventHndlr_requestData I check some conditions. This method grabs the data required for ajax call.

How can prevent the ajax call if this method returns false or some thing?

Comment: use return false or event.preventdefault().

Comment: Nope this is not working.. ajax call still happens with empty data though we return false.